# Is Firebase rules.MapDiff aware of changes to nested fields?

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

Looking at [the documentation here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rules/rules.MapDiff#affectedKeys), I can't tell if the various `MapDiff` operations such as `#affectedKeys()` are aware of changes to nested fields because all the examples use objects with a height of one.

Given the following document change, would `request.resource.data.diff(resource.data).affectedKeys()` include `"b"`?

Before:

```json
{
  "a": 1,
  "b": {
    "nested": true
  }
}
```

After:

```json
{
  "a": 1,
  "b": {
    "nested": false // <-- Changed to false
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`#affectedKeys()` **will** include root keys where nested values have changed.

I didn't realize the rules simulator supports literal values so it was possible to easily test this without creating test documents. Given the rules below, a `get` to `/test/1` will be successful.

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
  
    function test() {
      let before = {"a": true, "b": { "nested": true }};
      let after = {"a": true, "b": { "nested": false }};
      return before.diff(after).affectedKeys() == ["b"].toSet();
    }
    
    match /test/{t} {
      allow read: if test();
    }
  }
}
```